# AWSTATS - Daily updates

Tags: windows, batch-file, awstats

I would like to have automatically daily stats updates of my website.
I did a batch script like this:

```
rem c:Perl64binperl.exe….toolsawstats_buildstaticpages.pl -config=mobilekat -lang=IT -databasebreak=day

c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -update -databasebreak=day
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=alldomains >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.alldomains.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=allhosts >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.allhosts.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=lasthosts > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.lasthosts.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=unknownip > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.unknownip.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=allrobots > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.allrobots.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=lastrobots > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.lastrobots.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=session > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.session.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=urldetail > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.urldetail.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=urlentry > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.urlentry.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=urlexit > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.urlexit.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=osdetail > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.osdetail.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=unknownos >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.unknownos.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=browserdetail >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.browserdetail.html 
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=unknownbrowser >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.unknownbrowser.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=downloads >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.downloads.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=refererse >  awstatsawstats.MobileKat.refererse.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=refererpages > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.refererpages.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=keyphrases > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.keyphrases.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=keywords > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.keywords.html
c:Perl64binperl.exe "awstats.pl" -config=MobileKat -staticlinks -lang=IT -output=errors404 > awstatsawstats.MobileKat.errors404.html
```

but then when I open the page `awstats.MobileKat.html` I see `Never updated (See 'Build/Update on awstats_setup.html page)` and I see 0 of everything (0 visitors and so on…). If I remove the `-databasebreak=day` and I open the same page, everything seems to work perfectly. If this continues to not work I think I will do a task scheduler that runs my batch file daily without this `-databasebreak=day`.

Answer (score 0):

Awstats read log file and create summary text file in monthly basis by default.
It's mean: each month will have it own summary file : awstatsmmyyyy.DomainName.txt

Databasebreak=day mean: summary file will create in daily basis: each day will have it own summary file : awstatsmmyyyydd.DomainName.txt

I dont understand what is "***automatically daily stats updates***" you metion.

- If you want to run awstat.pl update by daily, you just to have a cron job/schedule job run daily.
- If you want to report by daily, currently I think Awstats have not support this feature. But, you can use Awstats update with database break by Day, and modify a bit of source code to get report by day, week, month, year....by date range, or whatever you want.